# UWP XAML BladeView control - scroll newly-created BladeItem into view

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using the `BladeView` control from Microsoft's Windows Community Toolkit. When the application window is < 640px, the `BladeMode` property changes to `Fullscreen`.

When a new blade is created in my code behind, I want the `BladeView` to scroll to the right so that new blade is displayed. It *seems* like I should be able to use `StartBringIntoView()` to accomplish this, but it's not doing anything.

Here's what I'm doing:

```cs
if (bladeView.BladeMode == BladeMode.Fullscreen)
{
    // current window width
    Rect windowBounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
    int currentWidth = (int)windowBounds.Width;

    // scroll to view
    BringIntoViewOptions opts = new BringIntoViewOptions();
    Rect target = new Rect { Height = windowBounds.Height, Width = windowBounds.Width, X = currentWidth, Y = 0 };
    opts.TargetRect = target;
    newBlade.StartBringIntoView(opts);
}
```

This is what my XAML tree looks like:

[image]

Comment: When new blades are added, they should scroll into view automatically. If it is not doing that in your application, please [submit an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues) with a reproducible sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to use `bladeView.UpdateLayout()` before calling `StartBringIntoView()`.

Example:

```cs
if (bladeView.BladeMode == BladeMode.Fullscreen)
{
    // update the layout so StartBringIntoView() works
    bladeView.UpdateLayout();

    // scroll BladeView to newly-created BladeItem
    newBlade.StartBringIntoView();
}
```

Comment: If you need to call UpdateLayout() then there is a bug we would need to fix. Can you please file an issue on github